# Version compatibility Matrix for Keycloak and Angular?

Tags: angular, keycloak, integration, keycloak-angular

I want to integrate keyclock 21.1.2 which is the LTS version. I am not able to find which angular dependacy is compatible with the different versions of keycloak.

There is angular-keyclock package available in npm.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular

But it does not mention which keyclock version is compatible with keyclock-angular.

Plase guide me on this. Where can I get info about the version compatibility matrix ?

I tried searching on official website i.e. https://www.keycloak.org/guides .

No info found on keycloak - angular integration.

Comment: There's matrix where you have information that keyclock 21 is supported by keycloak-angular 13-14...

Comment: You must have seen the matrix on https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular site. Keycloak-js is also a npm peer dependency for keycloak-angular. It is not the Keycloak application version.

Comment: `keycloak-js` is a client adapter for keycloak shipped with keycloak itself, so versions do match..

Comment: There is not LTS version of Keycloak available. Currently, as of today, it is the the latest version, but not LTS, which means Long-Term-Support. For Keycloak itself, there is not long-term-support!

Comment: Yeah, it is not written anywhere.